# Надо вывести номера команд не более 5 чтобы получить число 22

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pycharm

1- прибавляет 1

2-умножает на 3

Первая из них увеличивает число на экране на 1, вторая – утраивает его. Запишите порядок команд в программе преобразования числа 1 в число 22, содержащей не более 5 команд, указывая лишь номера команд. (Например, 21211 – это программа умножь на 3 прибавь 1 умножь на 3 прибавь 1 прибавь 1, которая преобразует число 1 в 14.)

```
import math
firstNumber = 1
lastNumber = 22
plusNumber = 1
multiplayNumber = 3
minusNumber = 5
numberOflevelsTree = 6

cs = 0
mainList = [[firstNumber]]
for i in range(1, numberOflevelsTree):
    underList = []
    f = []
    for j in range(0, 2**i, 2):
        tempA = mainList[i-1][math.ceil((j+1)/2)-1]
        underList.insert(j, tempA+plusNumber)
        if (tempA+plusNumber) == lastNumber:
            cs += 1
        underList.insert(j+1, tempA*multiplayNumber)
        if (tempA*multiplayNumber) == lastNumber:
            cs += 1
    mainList.insert(i, underList)
print(mainList)
if cs != 0:
    print('Всего способов:',cs)
```

Comment: А у вас в чем сложность конкретно? за вас составить команду?

Comment: Не нужно давать писать половину вопроса в комментарии, вся нужная информация должна быть в самом вопросе.

Comment: Какая проблема с приведенным кодом? Не работает? Работает, но не так как хочется? Какой вообще вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools


def multiplication(value, expression):
    return value * 3, '({0}) * 3'.format(expression)


def addition(value, expression):
    return value + 1, '{0} + 1'.format(expression)


def execute(*commands):
    operations = {1: addition, 2: multiplication}
    value = 1
    expression = '1'
    for command in commands:
        value, expression = operations[command](value, expression)
    return value, expression


for commands in itertools.product([1, 2], repeat=5):
    value, expression = execute(*commands)
    if value == 22:
        print('{0}: {1} = 22'.format(commands, expression))
```

Всего одна комбинация нашлась:

```
# (1, 2, 1, 2, 1): ((1 + 1) * 3 + 1) * 3 + 1 = 22
```